# Updating RowSet if table content is changed?

Tags: java, jdbc, cachedrowset, rowset

Is it possible to update/refresh a `RowSet`'s in case the table content is changed (for e.g. another application modifies it)? So this way I 'always' have an up-to-date version of the table.

I looked into `RowSetListener`, but these events seem to get invoked only if I make modifications to the `RowSet` directly. It would be enough to know that there was a change, I know... that's a lot :)

Please share your thoughts! Thanks in advance!
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no any way, for most traditional RDBMS. Just because of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Isolation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a RowSet can be refreshed. Just call its "execute()" method again.

Per the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/RowSet.html#execute%28%29):

> If this method is successful, the current contents of the rowset are discarded and the rowset's metadata is also (re)set.

A [rowSetChanged](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/RowSetListener.html#rowSetChanged%28javax.sql.RowSetEvent%29) event fires upon this refresh.

If you are asking if a RowSet can be automatically refreshed when data is changed on the database server: No way that I know of. You may not want to know of such changes, depending on your isolation level, locking, and MVCC strategy.